# Do unused imports in java effects performance and consume memory?

Tags: java, memory, software-design

```
import java.io.*;
class Myclass
{
 //Some programming code that does not call any java io package methods or variables
}
```

Is that program takes more memory or even worse affect performance of the software/app than the program that has no unused imports?

Comment: No. They just may the compiler work harder! With or without the unused import has no effect on the produced class file, which then has no effect on the runtime performance.

Comment: See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12620369/how-java-import-works).

Comment: Does that means it effects performance?Please elaborate.

Comment: Also duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153690/does-an-unused-import-declaration-eat-memory-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, imports are a compile-time feature (they have no meaning in the compiled code). They do not affect runtime behavior.