# Import library only for debugging

Tags: android, stetho

I am using **stetho** lib for debugging my app.

Gradle:

```
debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
debugCompile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
```

Application class:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Stetho.initialize(..);
}
```

But if I need to create a release version I must comment every time:

```
import com.facebook.stetho.Stetho; 
import com.uphyca.stetho_realm.RealmInspectorModulesProvider;
```

How to show the compiler that these libs only for debugging?
Can we comment on two lines without creating an additional class, using annotations or something like this?

Comment: I would use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31483962/8198240) approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include Stetho only in the debug build variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172308/include-stetho-only-in-the-debug-build-variant)

Comment: Yes, I saw this thread but I am trying to understand if there are other possible ways, for example annotations.

Comment: Creating an additional class to comment on two lines. I think it's not the best way

Comment: There is nothing bad in creating an extra class. Just hide it in some /utils dumpster and it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave the unused imports as they are. Your approach of `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)` is perfectly valid. And frankly the best way to implement it.

Unused imports have no impact on performance: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18153710/1396264). There might be a trivial increase in compile time, but no increase in runtime.

> Import statements don't make it to byte code.

You will need to change 
Gradle:

```
debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
debugCompile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Even if it doesn't create additional classes it still ships with release .apk

Comment: this way the non used imports still afect the apk size... if you dont care about it okay but if you target low end devices it makes a huge difference

Comment: This is not the right way to do it. code will still ship with the build.
Also compile is not deprecated and should be used as implementation